# Are Bigquery job logs stored?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

Using logging service https://console.cloud.google.com/logs?project=xxxx&service=bigquery.googleapis.com I'm not able to find logs related to job for UI or bq command line.

[EDIT ]

As suggested by @DoIT International `bq ls -j` show list of jobs but no log about the failure

[image: bq ls -j result]

Answer (score 2):

Use the following command to list the history of query jobs:

```
bq ls -j
```

The `bq` is the part of Google CloudSDK available here: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/

Comment: yes, it's prints the log but I need to seen the cause of the failure. I loaded a 25 millions-line file, the job failed without printing the line causing the crash.

Comment: @AliSAIDOMAR try to run it as ```ls --all -j``` to show all jobs, including these ran by other users and service accounts. You'll need to have ```owner``` privilege in the project to able to do that.

Comment: To see error details for a specific job, use: `bq show -j <jobid>`, and if you want to see the raw response, use: `bq --format=prettyjson show -j <jobid>`

Comment: I know it's an old topic but I tried to view error details by first listing all jobs, getting the last job_id that failed and then using it in `bq show -j bquxjob_3e54c2de_176da3953ff` but whatever job_id I pick, I always get an error `BigQuery error in show operation: Not found: Job vf-de-ca-nonlive:bquxjob_3e54c2de_176da3953ff`

Comment: @AleksanderLipka you need to prepend your project id and region, like `bq show -j my_project_id:asia-east1.bquxjob_3e54c2de_176da3953ff`

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-jobs#viewing_information_about_jobs

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Jobs: list API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/list) to collect job info and upload it to GBQ
Since it is in GBQ - you can analyze it any way you want using power of BigQuery
You can either flatten result or use original - i recommend using original as it is less headache as no any transformation before loading to GBQ (you just literally upload whatever you got from API). Of course all this in simple app/script that you still have to write

Note: make sure you use `full` value  for `projection` parameter

Info about failure should be present as below

```
  "errorResult": {
    "reason": string,
    "location": string,
    "debugInfo": string,
    "message": string
  },
```

see more details in https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/list#response

Comment: Thanks :) in fact with this service i can get job info but in my case "CSV table encountered too many errors, giving up. Row: 138130 errors: 21" it's not enough for me to diagnose the real cause of the error.